# Why do I lose all symbols when using in-ns to move to a new namespace?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

Running the following code in a Leiningen REPL:

```
(in-ns 'my-namespace.core)
(+ 2 2)
```

results in this error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: + in this context
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a new namespace using `in-ns`, the core namespace (`clojure.core`) is not referred by default. "Referring" a namespace means including it in your namespace in such a way that you can refer to that namespace's symbols as your own.

It is still possible to use symbols from `clojure.core` using **fully qualified names**, like so:

```
(clojure.core/+ 2 2)
```

The solution is to either:

1. Use `ns` instead of `in-ns`, like so: `(ns my-namespace.core)`
2. Refer `clojure.core`, like so: `(clojure.core/refer-clojure)`